# counting unique paths in 2D

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory

For a one-dimensional sequence $\mathbf{a}=[a_1 a_2 \space … \space a_N]$, there are exactly two ways in which I can read/scan (without repetition) this sequence i-e $s_1=[a_1 \space a_2 \space … \space a_n]$ and $s_2=[a_n \space … \space a_2 \space a_1]$.

Can we count the number of ways in which we can read a two-dimensional sequence $\mathbf{A}$, $A_{ij}=a(i,j) \forall 1\leq(i,j)\leq N$ that can be represented as a matrix of dimension $N\times N$. Also, path always starts from index-loaction $(1,1)$. My signal lies in the first quadrant of a grid graph.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html

Also, I am not aware of any name that is formally associated with this problem. Any input will be much appreciated.

(Note: I was searching for an answer and found this [Counting paths in a square matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25735/counting-paths-in-a-square-matrix) Although it sounds like a similar problem, the differentiating point is the fact that at each index $(i,j)$, next possible step is one of these indices $[(i-1,j) \space\space (i-1,j+1) \space\space (i,j+1) \space\space(i+1,j) \space\space (i+1,j+1)])$

Comment: What do you mean by reading a sequence?

Comment: So the number of paths from (1,1) on a grid graph? Like http://oeis.org/A096969?

Comment: @ copper.hat … i edited my original question to make it clear. By reading I imply a simple scanning mechanism with no repetition.

Comment: @ gilleain … thank you for pointing that out. i Have added a link for visual aid  in original question